# ITK difference betweeen SetInitialTransform and SetMovingInitialTransform

Tags: itk, image-registration

I am now using ITK library to image registration. I wonder, when setting initial parameters for ImageRegistrationMethodv4 type registration, shall I use SetMovingInitialTransform and SetFixedInitialTransform like in the tutorial, or just SetInitialTransform??

The "transform" in SetInitialTransform means transform for moving image or for fixed image? Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Please read this with caution--I do not have the library with me to test this answer; it's based on memory only.)

I believe `SetInitialTransform()` refers to the transform which is actually optimized by the registration method. In other words, it is a collection of transform parameters that specify an "initial guess" for the optimization process; these parameters will then start moving around at each iteration. (They are therefore applied to the moving image.)

I think `SetMovingInitialTransform()` and `SetFixedInitialTransform()` refer to static initial transforms which do no change at all during the registration process. They merely "set up" the moving and fixed images to desired starting locations, if you are not satisfied with their default positions in space.

If you have some simple 2D images, try testing this answer out with simple initial transformations, like a 5-unit translation transformation or something.

---

You could try reading the [ImageRegistrationMethov4 documentation](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageRegistrationMethodv4.html#a34f0656aaaa1d50c97e5a9c85ea39563) for a little more info.